# Python subprocess to execute external Command prompt scripts, trying to run one .exe file by passing file location

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, subprocess, command

I have to run one .exe file(RPA bot) using python code, later in that same code I might have to write other functionality as well for API creation. right now I am writing this code from Jupyter Notebook.

subprocess module's "popen" and "call" I have already tried by passing as a all type of strings.

**Command Prompt Script which I have run from python:-**

`"C:\Users\shubham.f.jain\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-19.7.0\UiRobot.exe" /file "C:\Users\shubham.f.jain\Desktop\FinalOCR\InvoiceAutomation\PDFReadwithNative.xaml"

**Python Code which is not working:-**

```
import subprocess

subprocess.call('C:\Users\shubham.f.jain\AppData\Local\UiPath\app-19.7.0\UiRobot.exe    /file  
C:\Users\shubham.f.jain\Desktop\FinalOCR\InvoiceAutomation\PDFReadwithNative.xaml')
```

I tried above code with passing all 3 arg as a separate strings as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to escape the backslash and split the command into a list of strings, so your Python code would look like:

```
subprocess.call([
    'C:\\Users\shubham.f.jain\\AppData\\Local\\UiPath\\app-19.7.0\\UiRobot.exe',
    '/file',
    C:\\Users\\shubham.f.jain\\Desktop\\FinalOCR\\InvoiceAutomation\\PDFReadwithNative.xaml'
])
```

Comment: thank you so much, it's worked and resolved my problem.

Comment: Could you please guide me, how to understand or find solution of such problem by our self, I am new in Python, was trying to understand Python Officially Documentation or other articles, but was not able to find the correct path. please suggest me

Comment: Just write a lot of code, make a lot of mistakes and learn. That's how I did it.